# c# - Multiple Select on Datagridview using BindingSource

Tags: c#

I know that to get single selected row on a datagridview using a BindingSource is this code:

```
BindingSource.Current
```

My questions is how to get the multiple current selected on datagridview using a BindingSource

Answer (score 2):

Guess it might be too late, but here is one solution...

If the DataGridView is bounded to a BindingSource and/or a List of Object, you might retrieve a List of Object accordind to the selected rows this way:

```
var myListOfYOURBJECTTYPE = dataGridViewEstados.Rows
                                        .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                        .Where(r => r.Selected == true)
                                        .Select(d => (YOURBJECTTYPE)d.DataBoundItem)
                                        ToList();
```

...or:

```
var myListOfYOURBJECTTYPE = dataGridViewEstados.SelectedRows
                                        .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                        .Select(d => (YOURBJECTTYPE)d.DataBoundItem)
                                        ToList();
```

**You can't forget to configure your DataGridView SelectionMode to FullRowSelect!**

Answer (score -1):

DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem contains the 'business' object it is bound to.
This sample:

```
DataRow row = (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
```